# Return view after using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am doing a search for a date in the database using ajax to call the function. The problem is that it gives me a 404 result when it should be showing it and the ajax enters in error mode.
controller code that works

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchDate(DateTime date)
        {
         code...
         return View(employees);
        }
```

ajax code

```
function SearchByDate()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("DateInputField");
            if (x.value != "")
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Employees/SearchDate',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { "date": x.value },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('Error!');
                    },
                    succes: function (data)
                    {
                        alert('Succes!');
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Date not selected!')
            }
        }
```

I ran the program with breakpoints and it exits with the right result but it is showing none and in the developer console i get ERROR 404!Not found! and also the ajax returns alert error.Please help! Ty

Update after some issues where fixed i get this error:
The view 'SearchDate' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed  type: 'GET',datatype: "html", then created a partial view rendered it inside and changed the function in controller to HTTPGET and returned partial view as result!

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple errors:

1. `[HttpPost]` at backend and you are sending a `GET` request.
2. `404` means file is not found, so your path might be not correct.
3. `succes` callback should be `success`.
4. `contentType` is not set instead you can look into `traditional:true,`.

Comment: the path is good because i ran the program with breakpoints and it did indeed reach the last return with results

Comment: how you ran the program? in the browser? can i see the url?

Comment: yes! i see the 404 there after the error alert from the result

Comment: i am not getting the 404 now... now i am getting something else... i will modify the question

Answer (score 2):

Use Query string in place of send data from data parameter.